# Dagger2 cannot access nullable. javax.annotation.Nullable not found

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2

I have a module to provide a Retrofit interface.

```
@Module
class NetModule(val base: String) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(object: Interceptor {
                    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                        val request = chain.request()
                        info("Request for ${request.url()}")
                        return chain.proceed(request)
                    }
                }).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder()
                .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                .serializeNulls()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .setLenient()
                .create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient: OkHttpClient, Gson: Gson): Retrofit {
        return  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base)
                .client(OkHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
                .build()

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideIdService(Retrofit: Retrofit): IdService {
        return Retrofit.create(IdService::class.java)
    }

}
```

The `NetModule` is used with `NetComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(NetModule::class))
interface NetComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

    fun inject(activity: Activity)
}
```

Which is injected in the application and stored in the applications companion object.

```
netComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder().netModule(NetModule("some_url")).build()
netComponent.inject(this)
```

In the Activity I then have

```
@Inject lateinit var idService: IdService
```

This gives a build error

> `IdService` cannot be provided without an @Provides or @Produces annotated method.

If I attempt to inject the `Retrofit` instance instead, I get a different error

> cannot access Nullable

The stacktrace shows class file for javax.annotation.Nullable not found.

I haven't been able to find anything referencing this error.
There is a StackOverflow post from 12 hours ago which seems to have the same error, but it has been removed. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983292/cannot-access-nullable-on-injecting-with-dagger2-in-kotlin

Comment: Can you please add some more error details.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I think I ended up creating a new blank project as I hadn't written much. The  project is here https://github.com/tpb1908/HNKotlin/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/tpb/hnk/dagger

Comment: have you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the javax.annotation.Nullable not found error, which I was able to fix by adding in the findbugs library which includes the Nullable annotation.

If you are using gradle add the following dependency:

`implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'`

Comment: You can also write the short version: `implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'`

Comment: Can anyone explain the rationale behind this solution? And why exactly the problem occurs in the first place

Comment: well. this is works and fix my dagger issue, when providing a string data type in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

> IdService cannot be provided without an @Provides or @Produces
>   annotated method.

This is because you have not injected your dependency where `IdService` is present. So dagger doesn't know how to provide `IdService` to it.

> The NetModule is used with NetComponent Which is injected in the
>   application and stored in the applications companion object.

You have to inject the dependencies where you want it to be used (here your `Activity`)

So write the injection in your Activity's `OnCreate`

```
netComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
        .netModule(NetModule("some_url"))
        .build()
        .inject(this)
```