# Inject presenter into activity via Dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to know how to inject Presenter in activity using code Following are details

Following is error message:

```
 Error:(12, 46) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerCategoryPresenterComponent
Error:(9, 46) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNetComponent
Error:(18, 10) error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter is injected at
com.headytest.android.MainActivity.categoryPresenter
com.headytest.android.MainActivity is injected at
com.headytest.android.dagger_component.NetComponent.inject(com.headytest.android.MainActivity)
```

Following are modules

```
  @Module
  public class NetworkModule {

String baseURL;

public NetworkModule(String baseURL) {
    this.baseURL = baseURL;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return cache;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.cache(cache);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    return client.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    try {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
}
```

`ApplicationModule`

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

Application application;

public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Application providesApplication() {
    return application;
}
}
```

`CategoryContractModule`

```
@Module
public class CategoryContractModule {


public CategoryContractModule() {
}

@Provides
@AScope
CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter providesCategoryPresenter(CategoryPresenterImpl categoryPresenter) {
    return (CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter)categoryPresenter;
}
}
```

Following are components:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
void inject(MainActivity activity);
 }
```

`CategoryPresenterComponent`:

```
@AScope
@Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules = 
{CategoryContractModule.class})
public interface CategoryPresenterComponent {
 void inject(MainActivity activity);
 }
```

`AScope`

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AScope {
}
```

Following is the code in `MainActivity`:

```
@Inject
CategoryPresenter categoryPresenter;

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     DaggerCategoryPresenterComponent.builder()
            .categoryContractModule(new CategoryContractModule())
            .netComponent(((App) getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .build()
            .inject(this);
}
```

CategoryPresenterImpl

```
    public class CategoryPresenterImpl implements CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter {

    @Inject
    public CategoryPresenterImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

    }

    @Override
    public void getCategoryLiast() {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume current error will be easy to fix, because it very much looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480371/1083957) issue.

You've instructed Dagger how to provide `@AScope CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter` but in activity you request Dagger to inject `CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter`. Dagger is confused at this point, because those two things do not match.

What you have to do, is simply add `@AScope` to `categoryPresenter`:

```
@Inject
@AScope
CategoryPresenter categoryPresenter;
```

---

I've checked out [your project](https://github.com/amodkanthe/test_apps). The problem was in `NetComponent.java`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

The issue is in line `void inject(MainActivity activity)`. Why is this an issue? Because by the time you construct `NetComponent` in [`App`](https://github.com/amodkanthe/test_apps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/headytest/android/App.java), dagger analyzes `MainActivity` for `@Inject` annotated field and sees `CategoryPresenter`. This means, that at this point Dagger should find appropriate provider/binder method in order to be able to inject `MainActivity` as declared inside this interface.

But it cannot find such a provider/binder method, because it is declared in an another component - `CategoryPresenterComponent` and this component (`NetComponent`) is not connected with `CategoryPresenterComponent` anyhow (subcomponents or component dependencies), thus bindings are not exposed.

Simply removing that line will make your build successful:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
}
```

---

For resolving *"Error:cannot access Nullable"* refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228615/1083957) thread, which suggest applying `compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'` to your gradle file.

After doing this you'll overcome that error message and will stumble on `retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method`, which has the same symptoms as `CategoryPresenter` had.

To overcome this issue you have to add a `Retrofit` provider method inside `NetComponent` (or to remove `@Inject Retrofit retrofit` from activity):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    Retrofit providesRetrofit();
}
```

After doing this you'll be able to run the app, but you'll end up in a NPE in `MainActivity`, because of this line:

```
.categoryContractModule(new CategoryContractModule(retrofit.create(HeadyAPI.class)))
```

You are referring to `retrofit` object, which is not yet initialized.

Long story short, your initial question has mutated a couple of times and in fact you had a few problems in your code. Still you have a problem there, because you are trying to use `retrofit` in order to construct a component, that was supposed to inject the `retrofit` for you.

Comment: Can you share `CategoryPresenterImpl`?

Comment: added please check

Comment: Are you sure that error stacktrace is completely same?

Comment: Not sure what might be the issue, current setup should be ok. Nevertheless, you can post a simple project with that setup at github, I'll have a look.

Comment: getting issue when trying to inject retrofit along with presenter

Comment: Error message is Error:cannot access Nullable

Comment: heyy sorry I am rasing multiple issue in same thread but after using above solution able to comile build but it is crashing when I am running app  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object retrofit2.Retrofit.create(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference I guess it is not able to initialize Retrofit

Comment: I have already told, that you will end up receiving a NullPointerException and have described why that happens.

Comment: SO should I set retrofit using setter for Presenter instead of doing it at inject time?

Comment: You need not pass `Retrofit` to `CategoryContractModule`, because `CategoryContractComponent` has declared `NetComponent` as it's dependency, thus any provider method inside `NetComponent` is visible inside `CategoryContractComponent`.

Comment: you mean like this categoryContractModule(new CategoryContractModule(retrofit))?

Comment: Also is it valid to have provide statement in NetComponent? I thought it has to be in Module only