# How to inject a Preseneter and View interface MVP dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Hi I am using dagger and unable to build project following is the error message I am getting

```
Error:(18, 10) error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] 
com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryContract.CategoryView cannot 
be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryContract.CategoryView is 
injected at
com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryPresenterImpl.<init> 
(categoryView)
com.headytest.android.category_listing.CategoryPresenterImpl is injected at
com.headytest.android.MainActivity.categoryPresenter
com.headytest.android.MainActivity is injected at
com.headytest.android.dagger_component.NetComponent.inject
(com.headytest.android. MainActivity)
```

Following is CategoryContract

```
public interface CategoryContract {

interface CategoryPresenter {

    public void onStart();

    public void onStop();

    public void getCategoryLiast();

}

interface CategoryView {

    public void onPreAPIRequest();

    public void onAPISuccess();

    public void onAPIError();

    public void setCategoryList(Result result);
}
}
```

Following is Presenter

```
public class CategoryPresenterImpl implements CategoryContract.CategoryPresenter {
CategoryContract.CategoryView categoryView;
Retrofit retrofit;

@Inject
public CategoryPresenterImpl(CategoryContract.CategoryView categoryView) {
    this.categoryView = categoryView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

}

@Override
public void onStop() {

}

@Override
public void getCategoryLiast() {

}
}
```

Following is Module

```
@Module
public class CategoryContractModule {
private CategoryContract.CategoryView categoryView;

public CategoryContractModule(CategoryContract.CategoryView categoryView) {
    this.categoryView = categoryView;
}

@Provides
@AScope
CategoryContract.CategoryView providesCategoryView() {
    return this.categoryView;

}


@Provides
@AScope
CategoryPresenterImpl providesCategoryPresenter() {
    return new CategoryPresenterImpl(categoryView);
}
}
```

NetComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);


}
```

CategoryPresenterComponent

```
 @AScope
 @Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules = 
 {CategoryContractModule.class})
 public interface CategoryPresenterComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

 }
```

Inject code

```
 DaggerCategoryPresenterComponent.builder()
            .netComponent(((App) getApplicationContext()).getNetComponent())
            .categoryContractModule(new CategoryContractModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this);
```

I am providing view with Provides in module still I am getting error message Any idea why?

Comment: Please include the NetComponent and MainActivity injection part. I guess it's a scoping issue? And I believe you're using constructor injection inadvertently here.

Comment: added please check

Comment: Yea, seems as I thought. In your mainactivity you inject `CategoryPresenterImpl categoryPresenter`?

Comment: getting same error if I replace with CategoryPresenter categoryPresenter

Comment: It should not be the same error, but it should complain about the presenter not being able to be provided instead of the view. You can't provide `@AScope` from `@Singleton`, which is why you get the error.

Comment: So how can I inject a presenter Presenter and View being interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Removing `void inject(MainActivity activity)` from `NetworkComponent` will resolve the issue. See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859366/1083957).